# OpenCV Boosting

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to know how do you get the classifiers choosen by the OpenCV Boost algorithm

```
cv::Boost boosting;
boosting.train(...); // Select some classifiers (I want to know which one)
```

Thanks

Comment: The CvBoost::get_weak_predictors can be used like there:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26078555/1271079