# How do I use AdaBoost for feature selection?

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, feature-selection, adaboost

I want to use AdaBoost to choose a good set features from a large number (~100k).  AdaBoost works by iterating though the feature set and adding in features based on how well they preform.  It chooses features that preform well on samples that were mis-classified by the existing feature set.

Im currently using in Open CV's `CvBoost`. I got an [example working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869954/opencv-c-problems-working-with-cvboost-adaboost-classifer/25960806#25960806), but from the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/boosting.html) it is not clear how to pull out the feature indexes that It has used.

Using either `CvBoost`, a 3rd party library or implementing it myself, how can pull out a set of features from a large feature set using AdaBoot?

Comment: This seems off-topic for several reasons: no clear question, requests for third party libraries, opinionated, and broad.

Comment: @JBentley - Thank you for your comment.  I would argue that the question is clear - how do I get AdaBoost working for feature selection. The body of the question is really to show I have done some leg work in this area. I don't want a 3rd party library recommendation, however if the solution is to use a 3rd party library then that would be great.  I would welcome suggestions as to how this question can be improved, because I would really like to get some useful responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim: I am not a user of opencv. From the documentation, opencv's adaboost is using the [decision tree](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/boosting.html#cvboosttree) (either classification tree or regression tree) as the fundamental weak learner.

It seems to me this is the way to [get the underline weak learners](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/boosting.html#cvboost-get-weak-predictors):

```
CvBoost::get_weak_predictors
Returns the sequence of weak tree classifiers.

C++: CvSeq* CvBoost::get_weak_predictors()
The method returns the sequence of weak classifiers. 
Each element of the sequence is a pointer to the CvBoostTree class or 
to some of its derivatives.
```

Once you have access to the sequence of `CvBoostTree*`, you should be able to inspect which features are contained in the tree and what are the split value etc.

If each tree is only a decision stump, only one feature is contained in each weak learner. But if we allow deeper depth of tree, a combination of features could exist in each individual weak learner.

I further took a look at the `CvBoostTree` [class](http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/classCvBoostTree.html); unfortunately the class itself does not provide a public method to check the internal features used. But you might want to create your own sub-class inheriting from `CvBoostTree` and expose whatever functionality.

Comment: This looks great, thank you! Im curious- if you are not an Open CV, do you know any other machine learning package, or did you research the answer from scratch?

Comment: np. I have experience with adaboost (written my own code) so I know the general idea.

Comment: I figured it out eventually, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

With the help of @greeness answer I made a subclass of `CvBoost`

```
std::vector<int> RSCvBoost::getFeatureIndexes() {

    CvSeqReader reader;
    cvStartReadSeq( weak, &reader );
    cvSetSeqReaderPos( &reader, 0 );

    std::vector<int> featureIndexes;

    int weak_count = weak->total;
    for( int i = 0; i < weak_count; i++ ) {
        CvBoostTree* wtree;
        CV_READ_SEQ_ELEM( wtree, reader );

        const CvDTreeNode* node = wtree->get_root();
        CvDTreeSplit* split = node->split;
        const int index = split->condensed_idx;

        // Only add features that are not already added
        if (std::find(featureIndexes.begin(),
                      featureIndexes.end(),
                      index) == featureIndexes.end()) {

            featureIndexes.push_back(index);
        }

    }

    return featureIndexes;
}
```

Comment: Were you able to pull it off ?

I meant, able to extract the features with this way ?

Comment: Yes - It seemed to work.  I tested it by training on a series of x, y points where the label was true if x^2+y^2 > some threshold.  I added a third parameter z which was random noise and added a small amount of random noise to y but not x.  The algorithm chose x then y then z which is what I would expect.